# MS-7996 how to turn off SpeedStep?

Tags: windows-10, speedstep

I have problem with my computer and want to turn off SpeedStep but can't find it in my BIOS.

I checked my BIOS but can't find it. Used google but also couldn't find a solution.

Anyone has any idea where to find it?

Answer (score 0):

Look for a BIOS option of "Intel SpeedStep" or "EIST" or "C1E" or "Turbo mode".

If you can't find anything and would like to avoid over-heating,
you could just reduce by 5% the "Maximum processor state", found in
*Power Options > Change plan settings > Change advanced power settings >
Processor power management*.